# my function doesn't retrigger animation when the loop starts. Traffic light flashing signal works once

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing this loop to switch between the traffic lights but want to make the animation yellow flashing. It works only once? The variables for each loop are all local.
I commented out some code but it should work fine.

```
document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = illuminateRed;
const yellow = document.getElementById('slowButton')
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = illuminateGreen
yellow.onclick = illuminateYellow;

function illuminateYellow() {
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "#EFB700";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.animation = " blinker 500ms linear";
  document.getElementById("slowLight").style.animationDuration = "3s"
  var timeLeft = 3;
  var elem = document.getElementById('flashing');
  var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 600);

  function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      illuminateRed();
    } else {
      //elem.innerHTML = timeLeft ;  time left display
      timeLeft--;
    }
  }
}

function clearLights() {
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

Comment: I can't find documentation of the `blinker` value in the `animation` style. Are you sure that's valid?

Comment: @Barmar `blinker` is a name of `@keyframes` it's user created name.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use animation, you just need add 3 before `linear`, than you need reset it when `timeLeft` is reached.
But, since you already using `setInterval` you can simply change it's color from there:

```js
document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = illuminateRed;
const yellow = document.getElementById('slowButton')
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = illuminateGreen
yellow.onclick = illuminateYellow;

clearLights();
var timerId; //should be global variable
function illuminateYellow() {
  clearLights();
//  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "#EFB700";
//  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.animation = " blinker 600ms 6 linear alternate";
//  document.getElementById("slowLight").style.animationDuration = "0.6s"
  var timeLeft = 4;
  var elem = document.getElementById('flashing');
  timerId = setInterval(countdown, 600);
  countdown();
  function countdown() {
    document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = timeLeft % 2 ? "black" : "#EFB700";
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
//      clearInterval(timerId);
      illuminateRed();
//      document.getElementById('slowLight').style.animation = "";
    } else {
      //elem.innerHTML = timeLeft ;  time left display
      timeLeft--;
    }
  }
}

function illuminateRed()
{
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "";
}

function illuminateGreen()
{
  clearLights();
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "";
}
function clearLights() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  document.getElementById('stopLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('slowLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById('goLight').style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
```

```css
.lights
{
  background-color: black;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.lights > div
{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  background-size: 4px 4px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black, transparent, black, transparent);
}
#stopLight
{
  background-color: red;
}
#slowLight,
#flashing
{
  background-color: #EFB700;
}
#goLight
{
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: #EFB700;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="goButton">go</button>
<button id="slowButton">slow</button>
<button id="stopButton">stop</button>

<div class="lights">
  <div id="stopLight"></div>
  <div id="slowLight"></div>
  <div id="goLight"></div>
</div>
```

Also note, that when you use `setInterval` you need use `clearInterval` not `clearTimeout`.

And as a side note, you should avoid using inline styles, it's better use attributes/class of elements instead:

```js
const elLights = document.getElementById("lights");

document.getElementById('stopButton').onclick = illuminateRed;
const elYellow = document.getElementById('slowButton')
document.getElementById('goButton').onclick = illuminateGreen
elYellow.onclick = illuminateYellow;

clearLights();
var timerId; //should be global variable
function illuminateYellow(e) {
  if (e) clearTimeout(auto.timer); //stop auto
  clearLights();
  elLights.setAttribute("lit", "slowLight");
  var timeLeft = 4;
  var elem = document.getElementById('flashing');
  timerId = setInterval(countdown, 600);
  countdown();
  function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft == -1) {
      illuminateRed();
    } else {
      //elem.innerHTML = timeLeft; // time left display
      timeLeft--;
    }
  }
}

function illuminateRed(e)
{
  if (e) clearTimeout(auto.timer); //stop auto
  clearLights();
  elLights.setAttribute("lit", "stopLight");
}

function illuminateGreen(e)
{
  if (e) clearTimeout(auto.timer); //stop auto
  clearLights();
  elLights.setAttribute("lit", "goLight");
}
function clearLights() {
  clearInterval(timerId);
  elLights.removeAttribute("lit");
}


function auto()
{
  clearTimeout(auto.timer); //stop auto
  clearLights();
  !function loop() 
  {
    const min = elLights.getAttribute("lit") == "goLight" ? 6 : 3, //minimum seconds
          max = 3; //max seconds

    if (min > 3)
      illuminateYellow();
    else
      illuminateGreen();

    auto.timer = setTimeout(loop, 1000 * (Math.random() * max + min)); //set 3 - 9 sec to repeat this loop
  }()
}
```

```css
#lights
{
  background-color: black;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

#lights > div
{
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  margin: auto;
  background-size: 4px 4px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(black, transparent, black, transparent);
}

#lights[lit="stopLight"] #stopLight
{
  background-color: red;
}

#lights[lit="slowLight"] #slowLight
{
  background-color: #EFB700;
  animation: blinker 600ms infinite linear alternate;
}

#lights[lit="slowLight"] #slowLight.fast
{
  animation: blinker-fast 600ms infinite step-end alternate;
}

#lights[lit="goLight"] #goLight
{
  background-color: green;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #EFB700;
  }
}

@keyframes blinker-fast {
  0% {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: #EFB700;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="goButton">go</button>
<button id="slowButton">slow</button>
<button id="stopButton">stop</button>
<button onclick="auto()">auto</button>
<label><input type="checkbox" oninput="document.getElementById('slowLight').classList.toggle('fast')">fast blinker</label>
<div id="lights">
  <div id="stopLight"></div>
  <div id="slowLight"></div>
  <div id="goLight"></div>
</div>
<span id="flashing"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to study that a bit more, I'm new to animation, and doing extracurricular work I thought make the light interactive. I"ll check n see how it goes...I am trying to keep it looping I had  IlluminateRed() triggers IlluminateGreen() which triggers IlluminateYellow() but should be flashing then it goes to illuminate() and the loop continues but the yellow doesn't flash again

Comment: With proper timer and animation reset it works fine. I've updated the my second example. Try to avoid reusing `getElementById` and such, it's better store elements in variables and reuse them instead. Also it's a good idea to identify what type of variable is, tt will help you with large projects (i.e. elBlah for elements, iBlah for integers, sBlah for strings, and so on)

Comment: yeah I understand your point, I'm still figuring out some DOM tricks n rules